# Highlight instances of a word in Microsoft Word Document with VBA Including text boxes

Tags: vba, ms-word

The following code finds specific words and highlights them in Microsoft Word document. The code works perfectly fine. However when the code runs it doesn't highlight words inside text boxes. I need to highlight words in a regular paragraph and inside the text boxes. I've been messing around with it, however I cant figure it out. Any ideas you might have to do this?

```
Dim Word As range

Dim WordCollection(3) As String

Dim Words As Variant

'Define list.

'If you add or delete, change value above in Dim statement.

WordCollection(0) = "Hello World 1"

WordCollection(1) = "Hello World 2"

WordCollection(2) = "Hello World 3"

WordCollection(3) = "Hello World 4"

'Set highlight color.

Options.DefaultHighlightColorIndex = wdYellow

'Clear existing formatting and settings in Find feature.

Selection.Find.ClearFormatting

Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting

'Set highlight to replace setting.

Selection.Find.Replacement.Highlight = True

'Cycle through document and find words in collection.

'Highlight words when found.

For Each Word In ActiveDocument.Words

For Each Words In WordCollection

With Selection.Find

.Text = Words

.Replacement.Text = ""

.Forward = True

.Wrap = wdFindContinue

.Format = True

.MatchCase = False

.MatchWholeWord = False

.MatchWildcards = False

.MatchSoundsLike = False

.MatchAllWordForms = False

End With

Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll

Next

Next

End Sub
```

Code was found [here](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/macro-trick-how-to-highlight-multiple-search-strings-in-a-word-document/)

Comment: A Word document is comprised of a number of StoryRanges.  ActiveDocument.COntent is actually ActiveDocument.StoryRanges(wdMainTextStory).  So its likely you will need to search the range in each frame in ActiveDocument.StoryRange(wdTextFrameStory)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a document-wide Find/Replace, you can use code like:

```
Sub Demo()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim Rng As Range, Sctn As Section, Shp As Shape, HdFt As HeaderFooter, h As Long
h = Options.DefaultHighlightColorIndex
Options.DefaultHighlightColorIndex = wdYellow
With ActiveDocument
  For Each Rng In .StoryRanges
    Call FndRep(Rng)
    For Each Shp In Rng.ShapeRange
      With Shp
        If Not .TextFrame Is Nothing Then
          Call FndRep(.TextFrame.TextRange)
        End If
      End With
    Next
  Next
  For Each Sctn In .Sections
    For Each HdFt In Sctn.Headers
      With HdFt
        If .Exists = True Then
          If .LinkToPrevious = False Then
            Call FndRep(HdFt.Range)
            For Each Shp In HdFt.Shapes
              With Shp
                If Not .TextFrame Is Nothing Then
                  Call FndRep(.TextFrame.TextRange)
                End If
              End With
            Next
          End If
        End If
      End With
    Next
    For Each HdFt In Sctn.Footers
      With HdFt
        If .Exists = True Then
          If .LinkToPrevious = False Then
            Call FndRep(HdFt.Range)
            For Each Shp In HdFt.Shapes
              With Shp
                If Not .TextFrame Is Nothing Then
                  Call FndRep(.TextFrame.TextRange)
                End If
              End With
            Next
          End If
        End If
      End With
    Next
  Next
End With
Options.DefaultHighlightColorIndex = h
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Sub FndRep(Rng As Range)
Dim Sctn As Section, h As Long, i As Long, ArrFnd(), ArrRep()
'Insert Find & Replace expressions here. The arrays must have the same # of entries
ArrFnd = Array("OldText 1", "OldText 2", "OldText 3", "OldText 4")
ArrRep = Array("NewText 1", "NewText 2", "NewText 3", "NewText 4")
With Rng.Find
  .ClearFormatting
  .Replacement.ClearFormatting
  .Replacement.Highlight = True
  .Forward = True
  .Wrap = wdFindContinue
  .Format = False
  .MatchCase = False
  .MatchWholeWord = False
  For i = 0 To UBound(ArrFnd)
    .Text = ArrFnd(i)
    .Replacement.Text = ArrRep(i)
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
  Next
End With
End Sub
```

Such code will process the document body, headers, footers, textboxes, footnotes, endnotes, etc. Superficially, one would expect to be able to loop through the document’s StoryRanges. However, the StoryRanges object doesn't work reliably with Find/Replace for headers, footers, & shapes - Find/Replace on a StoryRange with multiple header, footer, & shape members only ever seems to look at the first member.

For a Selection, you might use something like:

```
Sub Demo()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim Rng As Range, Shp As Shape, h As Long, i As Long, ArrFnd(), ArrRep()
ArrFnd = Array("Hello World 1", "Hello World 2", "Hello World 3", "Hello World 4")
ArrRep = Array("Goodbye All 1", "Goodbye All 2", "Goodbye All 3", "Goodbye All 4")
h = Options.DefaultHighlightColorIndex
Options.DefaultHighlightColorIndex = wdYellow
Set Rng = Selection.Range
For i = 0 To UBound(ArrFnd)
  Call RngFndRep(Rng, ArrFnd(i), ArrRep(i))
Next
For Each Shp In Rng.ShapeRange
  With Shp
    If Not .TextFrame Is Nothing Then
      For i = 0 To UBound(ArrFnd)
        Call RngFndRep(.TextFrame.TextRange, ArrFnd(i), ArrRep(i))
      Next
    End If
  End With
Next
Options.DefaultHighlightColorIndex = h
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Sub RngFndRep(Rng As Range, StrFnd, StrRep)
With Rng.Find
  .ClearFormatting
  .Replacement.ClearFormatting
  .Replacement.Highlight = True
  .Forward = True
  .Wrap = wdFindStop
  .Format = False
  .MatchCase = False
  .MatchWholeWord = False
  .Text = StrFnd
  .Replacement.Text = StrRep
  .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
End With
End Sub
```