# How do I search and highlight multiple terms in Microsoft Word?

Tags: vba, ms-word

My goal is to be able to run this script and have the document search for and highlight a set number of terms, typically 10+ terms. I figured out how to do this with [another script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60420311/highlight-instances-of-a-word-in-microsoft-word-document-with-vba-including-text) I found here, but every time I use it Word crashes.

Below is a simpler version I have pieced together from different forums/videos I found online. It does exactly what I want it to do **except** I can't figure out how to make it look for more than one term.

The **.Text = "Text"** works great but only for one term. If I list multiple then it only looks for the one I listed last. I have tested other chunks of code I found online but I can't figure it out.

I am hoping it is a simple fix, especially since the rest of the code does what I want. TIA!

```
Sub UsingTheFindObject_Medium()

'Declare Variables.
Dim wrdFind As Find
Dim wrdRng As range
Dim wrdDoc As Document

'Grab the ActiveDocument.
Set wrdDoc = Application.ActiveDocument

'Define the Content in the document
Set wrdRng = wrdDoc.Content

'Define the Find Object based on the Range.
Set wrdFind = wrdRng.Find

'Define the parameters of the Search.
With wrdFind
    
'Search the text for the following term(s)
.Text="Test"

.Format = True

.MatchCase = False

.MatchWholeWord = True

.MatchWildcards = False

.MatchSoundsLike = False

.MatchAllWordForms = False

End With

Do While wrdFind.Execute = True
    
    'Change the color to Yellow.
    wrdRng.HighlightColorIndex = wdYellow
    
Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: You need to create an array of the terms you wish to search for and loop through the array to find each term in turn, just as the code you reference in your question does.

Comment: What should I do when someone answers my question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Use your current routine as a function.

Here is an example.

```
Function FindAndMark(sText As String) ' UsingTheFindObject_Medium()
' https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69633517/how-do-i-search-and-highlight-multiple-terms-in-microsoft-word
' Charles Kenyon
'Declare Variables.
    Dim wrdFind As Find
    Dim wrdRng As Range
    Dim wrdDoc As Document

    'Grab the ActiveDocument.
    Set wrdDoc = Application.ActiveDocument

    'Define the Content in the document
    Set wrdRng = wrdDoc.Content

    'Define the Find Object based on the Range.
    Set wrdFind = wrdRng.Find

    'Define the parameters of the Search.
    With wrdFind
        'Search the text for the following term(s)
        .Text = sText
        .Format = True
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = True
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    '  Mark text
    Do While wrdFind.Execute = True
        'Change the color to Yellow.
        wrdRng.HighlightColorIndex = wdYellow
    Loop
    Set wrdFind = Nothing
    Set wrdRng = Nothing
    Set wrdDoc = Nothing
End Function

Sub MultiFindMark()
    ' https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69633517/how-do-i-search-and-highlight-multiple-terms-in-microsoft-word
    ' Charles Kenyon
    Dim i As Integer
    Const n As Integer = 4  ' set number (n) of terms in search
    Dim sArray(n) As String ' Create array to hold terms
    ' Assign values, starting at 0 and going to n-1
    Let sArray(0) = "Aenean"
    Let sArray(1) = "Pellentesque"
    Let sArray(2) = "libero"
    Let sArray(3) = "pharetra"
    For i = 0 To n - 1
        FindAndMark (sArray(i))
    Next i
    
End Sub
```

### Here is a revision using the code from ASH to handle the Array

```
Sub MultiFindMark2() 
    ' https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69633517/how-do-i-search-and-highlight-multiple-terms-in-microsoft-word
    ' Charles Kenyon
    ' modified to use methods proposed by ASH
    Dim i As Long
    Dim sArray() As String ' Create array to hold terms
    ' Assign values, starting at 0 and going to n-1
    sArray = Split("Aenean Pellentesque libero pharetra")    ' your list separated by spaces
    For i = 0 To UBound(sArray)
        FindAndMark (sArray(i))
    Next i
    
End Sub
```

With some of the changes showing as comments:

```
Sub MultiFindMark2() 
    ' https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69633517/how-do-i-search-and-highlight-multiple-terms-in-microsoft-word
    ' Charles Kenyon
    ' modified to use methods proposed by ASH
    Dim i As Long
'    Const n As Integer = 4  ' set number (n) of terms in search
    Dim sArray() As String ' Create array to hold terms
    ' Assign values, starting at 0 and going to n-1
    sArray = Split("Aenean Pellentesque libero pharetra")    ' your list separated by spaces
'    Let sArray(0) = "Aenean"
'    Let sArray(1) = "Pellentesque"
'    Let sArray(2) = "libero"
'    Let sArray(3) = "pharetra"
    For i = 0 To UBound(sArray)
        FindAndMark (sArray(i))
    Next i
    
End Sub
```

Note, this still requires the function.

Comment: Please note revised code

Answer (score 1):

This will do what you want.

```
Sub HighlightMultipleWords()

Dim sArr() As String
Dim rTmp As Range
Dim x As Long
sArr = Split("highlight specific words") ' your list
Options.DefaultHighlightColorIndex = wdYellow

For x = 0 To UBound(sArr)
Set rTmp = ActiveDocument.Range
    With rTmp.Find
                .Text = sArr(x)
                .Replacement.Text = sArr(x)
                .Replacement.Highlight = True
                .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    End With
Next

End Sub
```

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

Comment: `sArr = Split("highlight specific words") ' your list` The words in the parentheses separated by a space give your search terms. This is easier and more elegant than my method. As @Tim Rylatt mentioned earlier, the key is to put the search terms in an array and then cycle through them.

Comment: Yes, exactly. If it helped you, please upvote my solution. Thanks!